# I'm stuck on how to solve this one!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm stuck on how to solve this one!

[image]

Comment: We don't like to click through just to see the problem.  Whatever it is, what have you tried?

Comment: You can certainly think of a more descriptive title. The one you picked could be used on 78.23% of the questions of the site...

Comment: Related: [Coin problem on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) which proves that you can get any score of $7\cdot 4 - 7-4+1=18$ or higher.  There are very few numbers smaller than that to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say someone has a score of $100.$ By adding two $4$s and subtracting a $7,$ you can make it $100+1.$ By subtracting two $4$s and adding $7,$ you can make it $100-1.$

So for any score that can be reached you can reach a score that's one more or one less, *except* when one of those subtractions would give you a negative number of either the $4$-point items or the $7$-point items. You clearly cannot reach $1,$ $2,$ or $3.$ To get from $4$ to $5$ you would add two $4$s and subtract a $7,$ but that cannot be done because if the score is $4$ then you don't have one of the $7$-point items to subtract. Similarly you can't have $6.$ It's not hard to see that you can't have $9$ or $10.$

But what we did with $100$ shows that once you have a sufficiently large number you can have one more or one less. Thus it is only some small numbers that cannot be reached.